# Venn Diagram QS

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Each of a group of 50 students studies either French or Spanish but not both, and either math of physics but not both. If 16 students study French and math, 26 study Spanish, and 12 study physics, how many studies both Spanish and physics?

The answer is 4 but I am not sure how to use a venn diagram to find that. A venn diagram would help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Venn diagram:

[image]

The $0$'s all follow from the fact that no one studies 1,3, or 4 subjects.

We know:

$$X+Y+Z+16=50$$

$$X+Y=26$$

$$X+Z=12$$

So:

$$X+Y+Z=34$$

$$Z=34-(X+Y) = 34-26 = 8$$

$$X = 12-Z=12-8=4$$

Answer (score 1):

> Let $E$ be the set of all 50 students. Let $A$ denote the set of students studying french, $B$ the set of students studying spanish, $C$ the set of students studying math and $D$ the set of students studying physics.

Your hypotheses are that 
$$ A\cap B=\emptyset,\quad C\cap D=\emptyset\quad A\cup B=E,\quad C\cup D=E$$
and also that 
$$ |A\cap C|=16,\quad |B|=26, \quad |D|=12.$$
You want to know $|B\cap D|$. First off, you have
$$|C|=|E|-|D|=50-12=38$$
$$|A|=|E|-|B|=50-26=24$$
because they are disjoint. Furthermore, because $(A\cap C)\cup(A\cap D)=A$, with these being disjoint, this shows 
$$|A\cap D|=24-16=8.$$
The same reasoning applies to $(B\cap D)\cup (A\cap D)=D$, and it gives
$$|B\cap D|=12-8=4$$
I hope this helped. The Venn diagram follows quite easily form this.